# Finding only an item in an array of arrays by value with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is an example of my Schema with some data:

```
client {
  menus: [{
    sections: [{
      items: [{
        slug: 'some-thing'
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

And I am trying to select it like this:

```
Schema.findOne({ client._id: id, 'menus.sections.items.slug': 'some-thing' }).select('menus.sections.items.$').exec(function(error, docs){
  console.log(docs.menus[0].sections[0].items[0].slug);
});
```

Of course "docs.menus[0].sections[0].items[0].slug" only works if there is only one thing in each array. How can I make this work if there is multiple items in each array without having to loop through everything to find it?

If you need more details let me know.

Comment: So is your question actually that multiple `menus.sections.items.slug` can match "some-thing" and you want to return all of them and not just one. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: No the slug is unique and should only return one thing, but it returns all of the content within the parent arrays... so using [0] doesn't work.

Comment: Your quote "How can I make this work if there is multiple items in each array" I am asking you to explain what you mean if not matching more than one item as your question implies.

Comment: My question is written poorly.. Something like Schema.findOne({ client._id: id, 'menus._id': id }).select('menus.$') ... would return an array with one item, ie. docs.menus[0] ... is there a way to do this when you are deeper than a single array (array within array)?

Comment: Basically, I only want it to return the relevant menu, section, item ... not all menus, sections, etc.

Comment: Was there something in the answer that does not address your issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I haven't had time to test this until today. This works great and I will mark it as correct, but I am just curious if there is a way to combine this with a select so I can return other documents along with this in one DB call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is good for finding things in deeply nested arrays where the positional operator will fail you:

```js
Model.aggregate(
    [
       // Match the "documents" that meet your criteria
       { "$match": {
           "menus.sections.items.slug": "some-thing"
       }},

       // Unwind the arrays to de-normalize as documents
       { "$unwind": "$menus" },
       { "$unwind": "$menus.sections" },
       { "$unwind": "$menus.sections.items" }


       // Match only the element(s) that meet the criteria
       { "$match": {
           "menus.sections.items.slug": "some-thing"
       }}

       // Optionally group everything back to the nested array
       // One step at a time
       { "$group": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "items": { "$push": "$menus.sections.items.slug" }
       }},
       { "$group": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "sections": { 
               "$push": { "items": "$items" }
           }
       }},
       { "$group": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "menus": { 
               "$push": { "sections": "$sections" }
           }
       }},
    ],
    function(err,results) {

    }
)
```

Also see the other aggregation operators such as [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) for keeping other fields in your document when using [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).